# Adding widgets in xml layout

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-widget

I am building an android app and I have copied few xmls from some website.The thing am trying to do is to add the button at the very right in the bottom of the screen but getting no success.There are two layout and one of which is merged with other.I don't know where to edit and put the button.I am confused.please help me where to put it..
1st xml card_representation :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/card"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        android:background="@drawable/card_border"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/emv_card_background" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bankName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/card"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Bank"
        android:textColor="#999999"
        android:textScaleX="1"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cardNumber"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/card"
        android:layout_marginTop="77dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="3456 5456 6578 6543"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="21sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" >
    </TextView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/cardNumber"
        android:layout_marginLeft="95dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cardValidityLabel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:text="Expire"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="11sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cardValidity"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="12/14"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" >
        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/type"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="34dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/card"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/card"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:scal
```

2nd xml is card_detail:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/card_detail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#f5f5f5"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:background="@drawable/cardui"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/card_detail_title"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                    android:text="@string/card_representation_title"
                    android:textColor="#999"
                    android:textSize="13sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
                      <include layout="@layout/card_representation" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                android:background="@drawable/cardui"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/extended_card_detail_title"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                    android:text="@string/extended_card_detail_title"
                    android:textColor="#999"
                    android:textSize="13sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TableLayout
                    android:id="@+id/extended_content"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingBottom="7dp"
                    android:shrinkColumns="1"
                     >

                </TableLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/emptyView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#FFF"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/contactLessImg"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="140dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/contactless" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/paycard_back_text"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" >
        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Screen looks like with this layout as:
[image]

I want to add the button at the bottom of the screen in the right.Where should I edit..Please help
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go .Edit card_detail with this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/card_detail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#f5f5f5"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:background="@drawable/cardui"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/card_detail_title"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                    android:text="@string/card_representation_title"
                    android:textColor="#999"
                    android:textSize="13sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
                      <include layout="@layout/card_representation" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                android:background="@drawable/cardui"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/extended_card_detail_title"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                    android:text="@string/extended_card_detail_title"
                    android:textColor="#999"
                    android:textSize="13sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TableLayout
                    android:id="@+id/extended_content"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingBottom="7dp"
                    android:shrinkColumns="1"
                     >

                </TableLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
            <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="17dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="29dp"
            android:text="Proceed" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/emptyView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#FFF"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/contactLessImg"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="140dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/contactless" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/paycard_back_text"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" >
        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```